# How do I create square checkboxes in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How do you create a square checkbox in IE?

I use the following code to make sure they are square in other browsers, but I haven't found a good solution for IE.

```
input[type="radio"] {
-webkit-appearance: checkbox;
-moz-appearance: checkbox;
-ms-appearance: checkbox;     
-o-appearance: checkbox;      
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking for `check box` but code `type="radio"` shows that you are using `radio` buttons, what is it ?

Comment: This actually changes the appearance of the radio to a checkbox. I would like checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the type from radio to checkbox.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
    -ms-appearance: checkbox;     
    -o-appearance: checkbox;   
}
```